# D3JS: Automatic labels placement to avoid overlaps? integrate to angular 6 application

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular6, overlap

i'm working in project and i need to integrate a d3js plugin to an angular 6 application, i'm basing to this library https://github.com/tinker10/D3-Labeler

i want to integrate the labeler.js file and use it under an angular 6 application,
can any one know how to integrate this lib under angular 6,
any kind of help is appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import d3 into the component you want to use it, like this:

`import * as d3 from 'd3';`

Then use the `ngAfterContentInit` hook to attach your d3 magic to existing DOM elements from the particular component.

For example:

`ngAfterContentInit() {
   this.svgContainer = d3.select("#test").style("height","100px");
}`

Further more, I don't think D3 has any magic to avoid overlaps, you will have to write that yourself or find existing logic.

Comment: i already use the import of d3 to draw objects but i need to import this file to avoid overlap, in there repos in github they explane that we have to add the file in the relevant .html file which is not allowed in angular 6. so what i need is to import the file in angular 6 application

Comment: That lib you are talking about is nothing special, its just a JS file with a single d3 method inside it. So you can either import it or just copy pasta it into your component after d3 is imported.

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer, but i'm wondering how to do that.?